# "Office" field in Outlook 2010 Contact Card

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I'm working on updating our active directory information and I'm trying to find the AD field which populates the "Office" contact card field ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7htrj.png)).

I've updated the "Office" field in Active Directory {physicalDeliveryOfficeName} which updates the "Office" field in the full contact form of Outlook but it still doesn't change the contact card. I've gotten every other field in the card to update the way I wanted it, but nothing for this Office field, and I've already sunk a few hours of research into this with no results. I've tagged our environment versions.

So, does anyone here know where that field pulls its contents from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already have the contact saved to your local contacts prior to making this change? If so, it will not automatically update with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it totally right the  "Office" field is controlled by the Active Directory property physicalDeliveryOfficeName.

As this is correct and seamed to be working based on your screenshot I assume its more Exchange relaated. So I assume you are using an offline adressbook. So please make sure that this one is up to date via:

> Update-OfflineAddressBook -Identity ""

Then on your MS office client locate the cached OAB filed which are normally in:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\

Check the date here. You can also shutdown the Outlook client and delete the files. Then start the client and resync the OAB.